# Editing a child theme in Magento

Tags: php, magento, themes, magento2

I've created a child theme by adding files to C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\Magento\themename

In this I have a theme.xml file, a registration.php file, web folder, media folder and a Magento_Theme folder.

My question is as follows:

This child theme is using the C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank structure. For my homepage, how would I change the header file for example. It has a top menu, a search and a logo. How would I be able to re-arrange this? Or even the homepage. How would I make a new layout for this, to maybe have a 3/5 column of normal content and 2/5 content of a latest products (As an example).

Any directions would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

**Change header**

Overridde logo: Copy `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\header.phtml` to `app\design\frontend\Magento\themename\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml` and modify it as you want.

Overridde topmenu: Copy `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\topmenu.phtml` to `app\design\frontend\Magento\themename\Magento_Theme\templates\html\topmenu.phtml` and modify it as you want.

Overridde searchbox: It's a little bit different. Copy `vendor\magento\module-search\view\frontend\templates\form.mini.phtml` to `app\design\frontend\Magento\themename\Magento_Search\templates\form.mini.phtml` and modify it as you want.

Ref:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-templates

**Create layout**

1. Create file `app\design\frontend\Magento\themename\Magento_Theme\page_layout\new-layout.xml` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <update handle="2columns-left"/>
   </layout>
   ```
2. Create file `app\design\frontend\Magento\themename\Magento_Theme\page_layout\layouts.xml` with the following content:

   ```
   <page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
       <layout id="new-layout">
           <label translate="true">My New Layout</label>
       </layout>
   </page_layouts>
   ```

   3. Write the CSS file to declare the width:

      ```
      .page-layout-new-layout .column.left {
          width: 60%;
          float: left;
          -ms-flex-order: 1;
          -webkit-order: 1;
          order: 1;
      }


      .page-layout-new-layout .column.main {
          width: 40%;
          float: right;
          -ms-flex-order: 2;
          -webkit-order: 2;
          order: 2;
      }
      ```
   4. Clear cache

Ref:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117997/how-to-create-custom-layout-page-in-custom-theme
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html
- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-cms-page-layout/